# Como trasformar objecto AST en función ejecutable de Python

Tags: python

no logro transformar un objecto AST en una función ejecutable de Python

```
complete_route_path = os.path.join(Vars.APLICATION_PATH, aplication_dir)

for i in os.listdir(complete_route_path):
        with open(f'{complete_route_path}\{i}', 'r') as file:
            file_contents = file.read()

        # Parse the file's content into an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST)
        parsed_ast = ast.parse(file_contents)

        target_decorator = "@PathView"

        for node in ast.walk(parsed_ast):
            if isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef):
                for decorator in node.decorator_list:
                    if isinstance(decorator, ast.Call) and decorator.func.id == target_decorator.lstrip("@"):
                        code = compile(node, filename='blah', mode='exec')
```

Error:

```
code = compile(node, filename='blah', mode='exec')
TypeError: expected Module node, got FunctionDef
```

Intente de varias formas y me da el mismo error, seguramente me salto yo algo y no lo logro encontrarlo.

La idea seria que las funciones que me traigo del archivo tenerlas en un diccionario y poder ejecutar cuando lo necesite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como dice el error, no podés compilar un nodo que no sea ast.Module.
ast.Module es el "nodo raiz" devuelto siempre y cuando se parsee un código en modo exec.

Por lo tanto, debemos generar "artificialmente" un ast.Module. Este nodo, al ser creado, requiere dos argumentos:

- *body*: Una lista de nodos que van a conformar el código.
- *type_ignores*: No conozco del todo el proposito de este argumento, pero pareciera funcionar bien con una lista vacía.

A continuación, un ejemplo que elige aleatoriamente dos nodos y compila un nuevo ast.Module a partir de ellos:

```
import random
import ast

code = ast.parse("def sumar():\n"
                 "    return 1 + 1\n"
                 "\n"
                 "def restar():\n"
                 "    return 1 - 1\n"
                 "\n"
                 "def multiplicar():\n"
                 "    return 1 * 1")

new_code = ast.Module(body=[random.choice(code.body) for _ in range(2)], type_ignores=[])
new_code = compile(new_code, filename="hola", mode="exec")

print(compile(new_code, filename="hola", mode="exec"))
print(ast.unparse(new_code))
```

Que produce:

```
<code object <module> at 0x0000025523601840, file "hola", line 1>
def restar():
    return 1 - 1

def sumar():
    return 1 + 1
```

**Consejo para el OP** En este condicional `decorator.func.id == target_decorator.lstrip("@")` estás asumiendo que el atributo func del nodo ast.Call es un `ast.Name`. Pero esto **no siempre es así**. Por ejemplo, si parseas `@hola.mundo()` el ast.Call resultante tendrá en su atributo func un `ast.Attribute`. En realidad, los decoradores son tratados como expresiones normales, incluso podés hacer un decorador como `@a + 1` y va  a funcionar siempre y cuando el resultado de eso sea un llamable. Tenlo en cuenta si tu código puede sufrir este caso.

Comment: Funciona, y gracias por el tip!

Comment: `types_ignores` es un atributo de `Module` con una lista de los comentarios `# type: ignore` que indican al parser donde ignorar los errores con las anotaciones de tipos. Por defecto, el parser no tiene en cuenta los comentarios de tipos (ya en desuso), por lo que también ignora los _"types ignores"_. Habitualmente, se puede dejar como una lista vacía.